# cstheory vs AI stackexchange site

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to ask artificial intelligence related questions on the site?

There is a proposal already for an AI site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence but it seems the two converge well enough for this proposal to be redundant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm quite happy with machine-learning-type questions, but there's a lot of AI that's 'soft' and not bound up with mathematics or algorithms. I'd be less comfortable with those kinds of questions.

While I'm not planning to support such a site - (too many sites to track!) - I think an AI site might be useful for people in the area. TCS is unlikely to be a welcome place for folks in AI (especially the softer kinds).

Answer (score 4):

I view AI as part of CS, and therefore TAI as part of TCS. In other words, the criterion should be whether the question is in the theory side of AI. (OK, I made up the acronym TAI.)

Comment: I totally agree with this criterion.

Comment: Learning Theory

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be good to.  I generally think of AI as being a cognitive science, whose ultimate goals don't fit that closely with TCS, but the practice of TCS is usually much closer to here than the other cognitive sciences, and I think AI questions are probably a good fit for here.

Examples of questions that would be good here:

1. Knowledge representation;
2. Planning;
3. Theory of neural nets;
4. Concept analysis;
5. First-order learnability problems.

Examples of more problematic questions:

1. Anything philosophical, e.g., about characterising what is an AI;
2. Image recognition;
3. Natural language processing.

Comment: I had neural networks, search (A* etc.) and genetic algorithms in mind. I can see the strong vs weak and sci-fi style AI questions being out of place

Comment: @Chris: genetic algorithms are excellent examples of TCS questions, they sometimes raise really nice fundamental questions.

Answer (score -2):

Beta Q&A site for AI launched, so you can ask AI questions there:

- [http://ai.stackexchange.com/](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence/visit)